# Issue removing last two characters from rowname in a DESeq data frame

Tags: r, character, row

Thank you in advance for your help

I have a data frame that comes from  a few analysis and comparisons with DESeq2 library but that at the end is a large dataframe that looks like this:

```
> resEvN
log2 fold change (MLE): Group ELI vs NIT 
Wald test p-value: Group ELI vs NIT 
DataFrame with 56202 rows and 6 columns
                           baseMean       log2FoldChange ...[6]
                          <numeric>            <numeric>
ENSG00000223972.4  2.78292492689073    -0.24207616846296
ENSG00000227232.4  735.590503798565   0.0496174362951506
ENSG00000243485.2  1.46155527975626  -0.0765072904209051
ENSG00000237613.2  1.48824886356107 -0.00915380882252464
ENSG00000268020.2 0.746673256410335  -0.0111420404366476
```

In total has 6 columns and 56202 rows.

Mi issues is that I need to remove the ".X" from the end of the `row.name` without disturbing the data.frame.

So to convert ENSG00000268020.2 to ENSG00000268020

I tried several things but nothing seems to work, for example:

```
row.names(sub_resEvN)= substr(row.names(sub_resEvN), nchar(row.names(sub_resEvN)), -2)

or

substr(rownames(sub_resEvN), nchar(rownames(sub_resEvN))-2, nchar(rownames(sub_resEvN)))
```

Any idea?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not allowed to have multiple row names with the same name.  You'll have to create a new column with the modified names if there are duplicates. amd you still want this information.

```
rownames(sub_resEvN) <- sub("\\.\\d$","",rownames(sub_resEvN))
```

or

```
sub_resEvN$New_Column <- sub("\\.\\d$","",rownames(sub_resEvN))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is

```
 sub_resEvN$New_Column <-  trimws(rownames(sub_resEvN), whitespace = "\\.\\d$")
```